# safe __attribute__((constructor)) function classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it safe to use classes defined in you own project within **__attribute__((constructor))** functions? Has the objective-C runtime had a chance to do what it needs to do with your classes when **__attribute__((constructor))** functions are called? Or am I misunderstanding how the runtime loads classes and there is no difference between library class and your own in this context?

Comment: What have you tried? The GCC documentation says this attribute is not currently supported for Objective-C (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), and the Clang documentation seems to be silent on the issue.

Comment: @CRD Image constructors behave as expected using both compilers distributed with Xcode.

Comment: @Justin - so much for documentation ;-) Sounds like you should post your comment as the answer. Nathan, why do you want to use this attribute rather than `+ initialize`, which is run before any use of a class?

Comment: @CRD heh, what's worse - no documentation, or documentation that is out of date? by "as expected", I meant the initialization function is called before `main`. but it's not an answer to the meat of the question, which pertains to initialization order. Nathan wants to know if the objc classes have been loaded in the runtime by the time image constructors are called. i know of no documented guarantee -- without that guarantee, the order could vary by compiler or objc runtime version. so... no answer from me!

Comment: @Justin - turns out there is a documented guarantee it seems (answer added), though I'd use the designated methods myself.

Comment: just saw it, and ++ed it while you responded

Comment: I like to use __attribute__((constructor)) function for really simple bits of code, to get conceptually static const object for example kConstantArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...], I was also just curious about what other things it could possible be used for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll suggest you use `+ initialize` or `+ load` rather than the attribute, but that is my preference.

The `+ load` method of a class is called when the class is loaded by the runtime.

The `+ initialize` method of a class is called before any other method in the class.

From the docs for `load`:

> On Mac OS X v10.5, the order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. All initializers in any framework you link to.
> 2. All +load methods in your image.
> 3. All C++ static initializers and C/C++ **attribute**(constructor) functions in your image.
> 4. All initializers in frameworks that link to you.
>
> In addition:
>
> - A class’s +load method is called after all of its superclasses' +load methods.
> - A category +load method is called after the class's own +load method.
>
> In a +load method, you can therefore safely message other unrelated classes from the same image, but any +load methods on those classes may not have run yet.

Which makes it clear any attributed or `+ load` methods will run after the runtime is initialized. And as `+ load` is a method on your class and is run before any attributed methods then before either the runtime must have set up your class.

Answer (score -1):

Those aren't functions, they're just compiler attribute notations.  They won't change the generated code at all.

Comment: it's used to say "call this function when the image is loaded", and it is supported. the question relates to initialization order. think of it this way: *i have a framework which has an init function and some objc classes. can i safely use the objc types exported by the framework within the framework's constructor function? will they be loaded into the runtime by that point?*